# "Avconv" tag does not exist!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I just asked a question related to "avconv" and I was surprised that the tag for it did not exist. I do not have enough reputation to create a tag. I posted the question with "ffmpeg" tag instead. 
Would request anyone who is reading this to create a tag : avconv.
You may even consider to make ffmpeg and avconv tag-synonyms. But first things first, create a tag!

Comment: This should be a syn of libav correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taaaaa da! Done: [avconv](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/avconv). :)

Comment: Thank you. I will edit my question and add this tag. :)

Comment: @ChiragVora its done for you, regards.